# How to hide side menu of my List View. I cannot edit this page by adding Content Editor webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, css, modern-pages

How and from where can i hide side menu navigation. I could remove all navigation items from ***Site Settings > Navigation > Current Navigation*** but side menu still appears with no links. I cannot edit page to add content editor webpart as it is modern page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the site settings page

```
_layouts/15/settings.aspx
```

Click on the **Navigation Elements** from the Look and Feel section.

Uncheck the "**Enable Quick Launch**" checkbox.
[image: Navigation Elements - Enable Disable Quick Launch]

Click **OK** button

After disabling quick launch settings, we can see the side menu is hidden:

[image: Navigation Elements - Hide Quick Launch]

Comment: I have disabled **Quick Launch** the side menu is still appearing. Navigation settings is https://i.imgur.com/LWgY6nR.png

Comment: Your screenshot option is different than mine, I just got two checkbox, by the way did go through the navigation elements as mentioned above, in modern page you will get only two checkbox, it seems your screenshot is from classic page

Comment: Check again! There are two options in site settings 1- Navigation 2- Navigation Elements. In **Navigation Elements** I unchecked _Enable Quick Launch_ option and the screenshot is of 2nd one the **Navigation**